# error in java package after add watson developer cloud library

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I tried to make a TTS app using watson TTS and bluemix, but when I use this code

```
compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:text-to-speech:3.5.1'
```

to add watson developer cloud library, there is an error showing in MyApplication.java saying that:

> 'com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.BMSClient
>   package does not exist'

Please help.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you downloaded the relevant library(s) and included them in your project's classpath?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a contributor in the `com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:text-to-speech` module and we don't have any dependency to `com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.core.api.BMSClient`.

I think the problem is in another dependency not in the `text-to-speech`.